# Keeping the page vertically fixed on an element, when lots of content is revealed above (so causing scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a long page with lots of data tables of hidden content.

They are hidden as they are quite repetitive so not all users want to have to scroll past them all the time.

Frequently down the page there is the option to click to open up all of the hidden data tables.

The problem is, if you go half way down the page and click to open up the tables, all of the content being revealed above the current view causes the page to scroll down, meaning the user becomes disorientated as to where they are on the page.

I've mocked up the problem here. If you scroll down to one of the "show more" links nearer the bottom of the page you'll see what i mean.
http://jsfiddle.net/LnubwdzL/

I want the clicked link to remain static under the cursor so that the user knows where they are.

This kind of a solution:

```
$("a").on('click', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

... from other questions on SO, doesn't seem to cut it. Even if it ends up in the right place the page still moves about a lot before coming to rest.

Comment: try passing the same duration to `slideDown(duration);` as well as `.animate({}, duration);` method here. Does that work?

Comment: i.e. `$('a').on('click', function(e){e.preventDefault(); $('.hide').hide().removeClass('hide').slideToggle(400); $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 400); });`. Does that help?

Comment: Is it helpful ? it doesnt keep the scroll static but get you into it so the user can see the actual expand action and to find himself in all that new lines. http://jsfiddle.net/LnubwdzL/1/

Comment: Lower the time, change 2000 to something less like `200`, it will be sudden jump though. You can add 'easing' function if you like.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Clicking on the last link doesn't scroll all the way down

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla yes :-( tested on 7,6,5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly and as I mentioned in comments, I think you can set the same `duration` value to both your `slideDown();` and your `animate()` functions, and have them both inside the same `click` handler.

Your code may then become:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.hide').length>0){$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(this).offset().top},400);}
    $('.hide').hide().removeClass('hide').slideDown(400);
});
```

Hope this helps.

**Update #1:** Added a check on top of `animate()` so it does not animate when there is no `$('.hide')` element present anymore.

**Update #2:**
Take a look at this [resulting fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/mqfbyyk1/) of another experiment. Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

The way this works is:

- Upon click of an `anchor`, `offset().top` of clicked element is first
  stored in a variable named `prevOffset`.
- Current `$(window).scrollTop()` value is also stored in a variable named
  `scrollTop`.
- Then all the `.hide` elements are temporarily made visible via  `$('.hide').show();`.
- Another `offset().top` of the same clicked element is then stored in a variable named `currOffset`.
- All the `.hide` elements are made invisible again via `$('.hide').hide();`.
- `scrollTop` is then animated to a value calculated as: `scrollTop+(currOffset-prevOffset)`.
- All `$('.hide')` elements are animated via `slideDown()`.

**JavaScript:**

```
var duration=400,hideElements=null,scrollTop=0,prevOffset=0,currOffset=0;
$('a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    hideElements=$('.hide');
    if(hideElements.length>0){
        scrollTop=$(window).scrollTop();
        prevOffset=$(this).offset().top;
        hideElements.show();
        currOffset=$(this).offset().top;
        hideElements.hide();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:scrollTop+(currOffset-prevOffset)},duration);
        hideElements.removeClass('hide').slideDown(duration);
    }
});
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Makes sense, but doesn't seem to work. What I "think" is happening, is that the scroll target position is evaluated immediately on click, but as soon as other content starts revealing it is then no longer correct.

Comment: I think it needs more of a continuous feedback loop between the scroll target and the evolving element position as content is revealed. I'll keep having a play...

Comment: Let me try to understand, say for example `stuff 3` is almost at the bottom border of the viewport / screen and you clicked on `anchor` *show all* next to it, where should that content `stuff 3` be scrolled-to after this clicking?

Comment: if you click on the link next to ``stuff 3`` then that link shouldn't move, but should remain under the cursor.

Comment: @petesiss take a look at the **Update #2** above.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks! Seems to work perfectly. I tried a different way to do it myself using animate to reveal the hidden content, and using the step callback to check and reset position of scroll... think that could work as well and be a bit smoother, but no where near getting it working so far.

Comment: I think the problem with that approach would be that you will force browser to perform too many calculations in the `step()` calls, i.e. you would be calculating `scrollTop` value on a continuous basis. It might even bring lag into your animations.

Comment: yes, good point. If I get it working I'll post here for interest. Orherwise - thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries. Do "@" me when you do that. Thanks.